# How to create “lazy” tab navigation system on screens with react-navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, lazy-loading

I want to switch using the **lazy** system in the `<Tab.Navigator` I created. But when I try to go through the `navigation.navigate("Page")`, the page cannot be found because it is not rendered yet. How do I solve this?